# mysql command does not work in rails without the -u root

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I cannot seem to inspect my database with mysql and I'm a bit new and I don't know how to do this even after reading related posts.

I'm on `Rails 4.1.5` and the adapter gem is `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.0'`.

mysql version:

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23,
```

and I want to stay on this because it's too difficult to change the legacy app right now.

This is my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: some_development
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

This works:

```
mysql -u root -p some_development
Enter password:
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 47
Server version: 5.7.23 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show tables;
+--------------------------------+
| Tables_in_some_development |
+--------------------------------+
| activities                     |
| addresses                      |
| associated_products            |
```

But I'm doing this from root all the time. The password is the password I use when I log onto my mac. Is this fine?

If I try it like this:

```
mysql some_development
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jwan'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

it fails.

Comment: What is your question? I don't see any errors in here, or anything at all related to "inspecting" the database in Rails. Is there a problem? What are you doing in Rails that isn't working? In principle, you shouldn't use the same password for your login and database; they are unrelated and unconnected. That's not a problem, though, and not even really a concern most of the time. It's a security issue, but on a personal development machine, not one worth stressing over.

Comment: @JimStewart edited.

Comment: Now you've introduced another database name altogether, and you're trying to access it without credentials. You still haven't shown anything Rails-related other than a snippet of the configuration file. Does `arthouse_development` exist? Is it configured in `database.yml`? Do you have the username and password? Still not sure what you're doing.

Comment: I obviously don't know what I'm doing either.

Comment: @JimStewart edited again, the art_house development database was just supposed to be some_database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql -uroot -p

grant all privileges on some_development.* to 'jwan'@'localhost' identified by 'some_password'

mysql -ujwan -psome_password some_development

Be sure some_password matches database.yml

Of course some_password isn't literal it's the password you create